# How to draw a 'detached' ion with chemfig

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

What is the best way to have a 'detached but attracted' ion in `chemfig`? So I have a large molecule with a positive charge and want to position a negatively charged ion close by it.

According to my understanding, `\charge{}{}` or `\Charge{}{}` should be used. This works up until `\charge{X}{Y^+}`, but `\charge{X^{-}}{Y^+}` fails with some PGF error (roughly "can't divide 0 by 0"). My workaround is `\charge{\ce{X-}}{Y}`, but I don't like to use two separate packages.

Do you have any suggestions on how to better approach this?

My MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig, mhchem}

\begin{document}
    This is not quite minimal but shows what I intend:\\
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{[:90]-[@{op1,.5} ::-30]-[::-60](-[@{cl1,.5} ::60])-[::-60]C(=[::-60]O)-[::30]O-[@{op,.5} ::30]-[@{cl,.5} ::30]\charge{[extra sep=.4cm]130=\ce{X-}}{N^+}*5(=-N(-R)-=-)}
    \polymerdelim[height = 5pt, indice = \!n', h align=false, delimiters={[]}]{op1}{cl1}
    \polymerdelim[height = 5pt, indice = \!n, delimiters={[]}]{op}{cl}
    \schemestop
    
    \vspace{3cm}
    This is actually minimal and works with package mhchem:\\
    
    \vspace{1cm}
    \charge{[extra sep=.4cm]130=\ce{X-}}{N^+}
    
    \vspace{3cm}
    This is what I want but doen't work
    
    \vspace{1cm}
    %\charge{[extra sep=.4cm]130=X^-}{N^+}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
\charge{[extra sep=.4cm]130=\printatom{X^-}}{N^+}
```